# Running on Phillips device

Tags: android, device

It is really bothering now, I tried to update the driver to Google USB Driver but windows says

> "Windows couldn't find driver software for your device"

I couldn't find Philips in the OEM Drivers list either. So i don't know what to do. 
If it helps the phone has a 4.2.2 android version

Thanks in advance

Comment: check this link https://www.support.philips.com/support/downloads.jsp?userLanguage=en&userCountry=us

Comment: Try connecting your phone and using Vysor chrome app to view your phone in desktop. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vysor-beta/gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable developer options on your phone and check 'Enable USB Debugging'

On your Phone... Go to your settings: Go to "about phone" Tap on "Build Number" 7 times. This enables developer options Go to Developer options (in the settings app) Check - Enable USB Debugging Did you make sure to install the [adb](http://androidxda.com/download-philips-usb-driver) drivers for your phone? Also make sure you have enabled debug mode on your device. If neither of those are the issue, maybe check here for further troubleshooting help.

When you connect your phone to your computer with Android studio running, you should see a dialog box asking for permission for your computer to debug your phone. Tap Yes and accept those permissions.

You should be set from there! Hit 'Run' in Android Studio and you should be good to go.